# Java get available X and Y in grid

Tags: java, oop, object

I have some `Product` objects with the properties `locationX` and `locationY`

```
public class Product {

    private int locationX;
    private int locationY;

    //Getters & Setters... etc
}
```

The locationX and locationY are always different, there can't be 2 Product object with the same location. Every object has a different location, like:
0-0 | 0-1 | 0-2 | 1-0 | 1-1 | 2-1 | 2-2

Let's say we have an ArrayList with Product objects with these locations:
0-2 , 1-2 , 0-0 , 1-0

The ArrayList is mixed. What code do I need to get the first available location (0-1)? I've been trying to find this out for over a day but I can't seem to get it right.

Thank you.

Edit: I don't need to create a new Product, but just need the first available coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You should also `override` `equals` to be able to compare the `x,y` coordinates between objects.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Product p = (Product) obj;
    if (this.locationX != p.locationX|| this.locationY != p.locationY ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, when creating products, you could do something like this:

```
Product p1 = new Product();
p1.SetX = 0;
p1.SetY  = 1;
Product p2 = new Product();
p2.SetX = 1;
p2.SetY  = 2;

if(!p1.equals(p2))
   //Create more products
```

To access your variables, you could create `public` fields as I did, or you could also create the getters and setters as you have in your code

**EDIT**

It seems that you just need your getters and setters.

```
//Do the same for Y

public void setX(int value){
    this.locationX = value;
}

public int getX(){
    return this.locationX;
}

ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();

list.add(p1);

list.get(0); //Will get you the first element
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with the `Product`s then loop through it with a for loop.  In the for loop add all the `x`s to an array and add all the `y`s from each `Product`.  Once this is complete create an infinite for loop which will check if the `x`s contains the current value in the for loop.  If it does not then set the `x` for the product you are making with the current value in the loop.  Do the same thing for the `y`s

This will find the first non-used x and first non-used y.